# what's the size of AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

New to aws and vpc. Document says

> You are initially limited to launching 20 Amazon EC2 instances at any one time and a maximum VPC size of /16 (65,536 IPs)

It doesn't really help me get the idea of 'Size' in terms of MB? GB? I thought VPC represents the Private Virtual Space I get on AWS under my account. When talking about space, my mind set is always in terms of 'MB', 'GB'. Maybe I should not think VPC in this way?

Comment: "Virtual private cloud (VPC) — A virtual network dedicated to your AWS account. " - https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/

Comment: @James Z so VPC is not a hard-drive/memory space that we can speak in terms of mb/gb?

Comment: @James Z document says it's an isolated portion of the AWS cloud. The word 'portion' to me sounds like a space that i can save things on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPC is your own private network within AWS infrastructure.

> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) is a service that lets you launch AWS resources in a logically isolated virtual network that you define.

Inside you can launch resources, such as EC2, ELB and RDS which will have their own ENI which provides the IP address(es) allocation for these resources.

The total address allocation is the value described, this the total private IPs available within the VPC.

Comment: document says it's an isolated portion of the AWS cloud. The word 'portion' to me sounds like a space that i can save things on. So VPC is not really a hard drive or memory on aws cloud, right? @Chris Williams @ Chris Williams

Comment: It is not, its an isolated network from other VPCs both in your account others.

Comment: Thank you Chris, mind quickly tell me what's the benefit of 'isolated network'? what could be wrong with not isolated networks? @Chris Williams @ Chris Williams

Comment: The isolated part means that your resources will not share the same network space as others resources. You have complete autonomy to define the security and control what goes in and out of your network :)

Answer (score 1):

The VPC is just a container, your own virtual private cloud that is similar to a private network. It allows you to theoretically run up to approximately 65,000 EC2 instances (virtual machines), the largest of which currently come with 24 TB of RAM (useful e.g. for large-scale SAP workloads). You can also add Elastic Block Store (EBS) volumes (virtual hard disks) to these instances of virtually unlimited size. If that isn’t enough, you can create additional VPCs.

So, simply said: You can virtually run any number of servers with a virtually unlimited amount of memory and disk space in AWS.

The initial limit of 20 instances per VPC is to protect you from accidentally starting too many machines, like, say 10,000 at once, and run up a bill you don’t expect. Once you’re proficient enough you can open a support ticket in order to lift this limitation.